# How to show any custom error messages in modal by ajax request Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to validate user's request using ajax submit form in bootstrap modal.

I have a form:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @site_admin], remote: true do |f| %>
    <div id="error_explanation" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control', required: true %><br/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <div class="text-left">
        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-blue p-l-40 p-r-40">Cancel</button>
        <%= button_tag @site_admin.new_record? ? 'Create Site Admin' : 'Update Site Admin', type: 'submit', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-base p-l-40 p-r-40' %>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

model:

```
class SiteAdmin < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'users'

  def self.search(params)
    already_exists = where('email = ?', params[:email])
    errors.add(:base, "email already exists ") if already_exists.size > 0
  end
end
```

new.js.erb:

```
// Title for Add
$('#dialog h4').html("Add Site Admin");

// Render the edit form
$('.modal-body').html('<%= j render('form') %>');

// Show the dynamic dialog
$('#dialog').modal("show");
console.log('ddd')

$("form.new_site_admin").on("ajax:error", function (event, xhr) {
    console.log('sswww')
    var e, errors, i, len;
    errors = jQuery.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
    $('#error_explanation').empty();
    $('#error_explanation').append('<ul>');
    for (i = 0, len = errors.length; i < len; i++) {
        e = errors[i];
        $('#error_explanation').append('<li>' + e + '</li>');
    }
    $('#error_explanation').append('</ul>');
    return $('#error_explanation').show();
});
```

create method:

```
def create
    respond_to do |format|
      @already_exists = SiteAdmin.search(site_admin_params)
      unless @already_exists.size > 0
        @site_admin = SiteAdmin.new(site_admin_params)
        if @site_admin.save
          @site_admin.update_column(:confirmed_at, Time.now)
          password = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)[0..10]
          user = User.where(email: @site_admin.email).first_or_initialize
          user.attributes = {password: password, password_confirmation: password, role: 'admin'}
          UserMailer.send_credentials(@site_admin.email, password).deliver_now if user.save!
          format.json {head :no_content}
          format.js {flash[:notice] = 'Site Admin has been created successfully.'}
        else
          format.json {render json: @site_admin.errors.full_messages,
                              status: :unprocessable_entity}
        end
      else
        format.json {render json: @already_exists.errors.full_messages,
                            status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end
```

The problem is that I cant able to show error messages in model. Error like: `this email is already exists in the system.`

I want to create a generic way to handle this but can't able to show it properly.

The error I am seeing is:

```
Started POST "/admin/site_admins" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-01 16:55:17 +0500
Processing by Admin::SiteAdminsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "site_admin"=>{"email"=>"aaa@aaa.com"}, "button"=>""}
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" WHERE (email = 'aaa@aaa.com')
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 121ms (ActiveRecord: 11.4ms)



NameError (undefined local variable or method `errors' for #<Class:0x007f470c454110>):

app/models/site_admin.rb:6:in `search'
app/controllers/admin/site_admins_controller.rb:17:in `block in create'
app/controllers/admin/site_admins_controller.rb:16:in `create'
```

Any best practice way as well please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you. The **errors** is used only with objects. We can use it as is in **instance** methods not in **class** methods.

Following approach is the standard way to achieve model level validations before saving record to database.

## Model :

```
  class SiteAdmin < ApplicationRecord
      self.table_name = 'users'
      before_save :search 

      def search
        already_exist = SiteAdmin.where('email = ?', self.email).limit(1)
        errors.add(:base, "email already exists ") if already_exist
      end
    end
```

## Controller :

```
def create
      respond_to do |format|
          @site_admin = SiteAdmin.new(site_admin_params)
          if @site_admin.save
            @site_admin.update_column(:confirmed_at, Time.now)
            password = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)[0..10]
            user = User.where(email: @site_admin.email).first_or_initialize
            user.attributes = {password: password, password_confirmation: password, role: 'admin'}
            UserMailer.send_credentials(@site_admin.email, password).deliver_now if user.save!
            format.json {head :no_content}
            format.js {flash[:notice] = 'Site Admin has been created successfully.'}
          else
            format.json {render json: @site_admin.errors.full_messages,
                                status: :unprocessable_entity}
          end
      end
    end
```

Comment: Its keep entering emails in the system which it shouldn't. It should show error and should do rollback. Not working :)

Comment: It handles rollback and errors wont get showed automatically, make sure to display errors in edit.html.erb.

Comment: It does not. :) I am forced to do: `before_validation :search, on: :create`. As far as error are concerned I have managed to show them in new.js.erb. Also as I am working in rails 5 so displaying errors from ajax response using turbolinks 5 has changed a lot. :) I am going to accept your answer because you gave me right direction. I you have any reason to use `before_validation :search, on: :create` you can share as well.